# Create String list in Groovy

Tags: list, groovy, gstring, type-coercion

The following code in Groovy adds `GString`s to the list:

```
List<String> args = [ 'cmd', "-Dopt=${value}" ]
```

When I create a `ProcessBuilder` with this list, I get a `ClassCastException`. What's a groovy way to coerce the list elements to the correct type?

Comment: I added a comment about avoiding ProcessBuilder altogether to my answer (I am posting this incase you missed it)...  It might save you some work :-)

Comment: One of my biggest peeves with Groovy is that it doesn't convert the type for you in this specific situation. The compiler knows the types, so it should be able to deal with this just as easily as if you'd assigned it to a String. :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Or, you can do:

```
List<String> args = [ 'cmd', "-Dopt=${value}"] as String[]
```

or

```
List<String> args = [ 'cmd', "-Dopt=${value}"]*.toString()
```

---

actually, why are you using ProcessBuilder out of interest?  Groovy adds ways to do [process management](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management), and even adds three `execute` [methods to List](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#execute%28%29)

You can do (this is on OS X or Linux):

```
def opt = '-a'

println( [ 'ls', "$opt" ].execute( null, new File( '/tmp' ) ).text )
```

which prints out the files in my `/tmp` folder

Comment: Note that both do a bit too much work: The first one converts the initial `List` to a `String[]` and that back to a `List`, the second one creates a copy of the `List` as well and calls `toString()` on every element.

Comment: @Joachim Yeah, but they both look cleaner (IMHO) than embedding `toString` inside the list on specific elements (and it makes it less likely that you missed an element)

Comment: very true. Also this is *highly* unlikely to be the critical element on any code-path.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` also accepts a `String[]` - so the first alternative can be replaced to be: `String[] args = [ 'cmd', "-Dopt=${value}"] as String[]`

Comment: Re `execute`: I need to call `redirectErrorStream()` but thanks for the suggestion. I could use it in a different place.

Comment: @Aaron you can call `consumeProcessOutput(OutputStream output, OutputStream error)` on the [`Process`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html) object returned by `execute()`

Comment: tim_yates: +1 but it's not 100% the same. For example, output and error are no longer in sync when I do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
List<String> args = [ 'cmd', "-Dopt=${value}".toString() ]
```

because the later is a [`GString`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString).

Answer (score 1):

I did a test:

```
def value = "abc"
List<String> args = [ 'cmd', "-Dopt=${value}"];

System.out.println (args.getClass());

System.out.println (args.get(0).getClass());
System.out.println (args.get(1).getClass());
```

The output was:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
class java.lang.String
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
```

Changing the code a bit to be:

```
def value = "abc"
List<String> args = [ 'cmd', "-Dopt=${value}".toString()];

System.out.println (args.getClass());

System.out.println (args.get(0).getClass());
System.out.println (args.get(1).getClass());
```

produced this:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
```

Should do the trick, but I'm not 100% sure this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Minor hint: I find `System.out.println(args*.getClass())` to be easier to write and produce nicer output ;-)

Comment: @Joachim, Cool! (or should I say, Groovy!)